# What's the difference between "lifecycle callbacks" and "entity listeners"?

Tags: doctrine-orm

Lifecycle callbacks are registered on the *entity*:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-callbacks

Event listeners are registered for *all* entities. However, Doctrine now also features so called "entity listeners" (i.e. event listeners, registered at the *entity*-level):
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners

Unfortunately, the docs don't say anything about the difference between the two. When to use which? In particular: Is any one called asynchronously?

Answer (score 2):

The main difference that for listeners you may use external dependencies. In other words, you may change not only an entity itself.

While with callbacks you may only change internal fields of the entity, but not other entities, or make whatever actions you need (log, make HTTP-requests, create another objects and so on).